# In Python during importing Tweepy library like | from tweepy import * getting error

Tags: python, wildcard, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitter-streaming-api

from tweepy import *

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

**------getting this error------**

**Unused import api from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import debug from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import AppAuthHandler from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**
**Unused import Cache from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import FileCache from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**
**Unused import MemoryCache from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**
**Unused import Cursor from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import RateLimitError from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import TweepError from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

**Unused import DirectMessage from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)**

Comment: Try import tweepy without the *. I don't think the * wildcard is necessary, that is why you are getting all the wildcard errors.

Answer (score 0):

These are Pylint warnings, not errors.
The Tweepy import itself should still have been successful.

Comment: yeah you are right but I'm getting 401 .... continuously not getting extract data from code

Comment: That's a separate question/issue, but there could be multiple possible reasons for that. See https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting.

Comment: I got solution this is because of time and date  * Twitter keeps track of the current time. 
 * If an API request to authenticate comes from a server that claims it is a time that is outside of 15 minutes of Twitter time, it will fail with a 401 error.